# Mongodump using DBRef criteria and indexes?

Tags: mongodb, dbref, mongodump

I want to dump some part of a database, especially some part of a collection using the -q / --query option. Here is what I'm doing:

```
mongodump --host ... -o ... -q "{ pipe: DBRef(\"pipe\", ObjectId($2)) }"
```

The dump is operating but is strongly slow. There are 3M objects, and there is an index on the `pipe` attribute, so things shouldn't be as slow. It looks like the query is scanning the whole collection.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can switch on profiler and see what is happening. Basicly when you specifiy a query you dump will only run this query and convert the answer to the dump. First i thougth it will snapshot the query but no.

With profiler i had the following results :

for this : mongodump -h localhost:27417 -u ... -p ... -d test1 -c t

```
connected to: localhost:27417
Fri Aug 30 11:47:56.288 DATABASE: test1  to     dump/test1
Fri Aug 30 11:47:56.289     test1.t to dump/test1/t.bson
Fri Aug 30 11:47:56.291          101 objects
Fri Aug 30 11:47:56.291     Metadata for test1.t to dump/test1/t.metadata.json
```

I had this in the profiler:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "test1.t",
    "query" : {
        "query" : {

        },
        "$snapshot" : true
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 101,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(499),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(2),
            "w" : NumberLong(4)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 101,
    "responseLength" : 11410,
    "millis" : 0,
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-08-30T09:54:18.605Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [
        {
            "user" : "__system",
            "userSource" : "local"
        }
    ],
    "user" : "__system@local"
}
```

For this: mongodump -h localhost:27417 -u ... -p ... -d test1 -c t -q {\'b.b\':8}, i had this:

```
connected to: localhost:27417
Fri Aug 30 11:58:15.332 DATABASE: test1  to     dump/test1
Fri Aug 30 11:58:15.334     test1.t to dump/test1/t.bson
Fri Aug 30 11:58:15.335          1 objects
Fri Aug 30 11:58:15.336     Metadata for test1.t to dump/test1/t.metadata.json
```

In the profiler:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "test1.t",
    "query" : {
        "b.b" : 8
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(174),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(3),
            "w" : NumberLong(4)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 1,
    "responseLength" : 134,
    "millis" : 0,
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-08-30T09:58:15.335Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [
        {
            "user" : "__system",
            "userSource" : "local"
        }
    ],
    "user" : "__system@local"
}
```

That means it utilizes the index what i specified so some other thing probably the bottleneck or the query is not supported by the index you specified.